# Moving two files with Bash MV and expansion

Tags: bash

Hey guys I seem to remember a way (with I believe shoptglob) to move several
files at once, I just can't remember the syntax

I believe the format was something similar to

```
mv /tmp/filename.foo'(.gz|.cdx)' .
# move filename.foo.gz and filename.foo.cdx to current directory
```

Or some such, what is the exact syntax? it has something to do with expansion if I remember correctly

Comment: I think you don't use the quotes, and change the parenthesis to braces. Can't check just now though since windows.

Comment: Both `[]` and `{}` didn't work, I think it might be something with the dot?

Comment: I think it needs a comma (which chepner's answer seems to confirm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways:

1. Use brace expansion.

   ```
   mv /tmp/filename.foo.{gz,cdx} .
   ```
2. Use the `extglob` option (which is what you seem to be thinking of).

   ```
   shopt -s extglob
   mv /tmp/filename.foo.@(gz|cdx) .
   ```

Comment: Yep exactly what I was looking for, +1 for knowing what I'm talking about, waiting to accept. I forgot it was a comma not a pipe ;)